# How to prevent "billion laughs" DoS attack in Python's xlrd?

Tags: python, xml, xlsx, xlrd, client-side-attacks

The [Billion Laughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs) DoS attack seems preventable by simply stopping entities in XML files from being expanded. Is there a way to do this in Python's xlrd library (i.e. a flag of some sort)? If not, is there a recommended way to avoid the attack?

Comment: I haven't tried, but what happens if you try and load the example XML file (from the in the wikipedia article) with xlrd? Does it handle it?

Comment: [relevant link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/defusedxml/)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr It stalls for a very, very long time. I haven't waited it out all the way but I'd expect it eventually results in an overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not with xlrd by itself

There is no option in xlrd at this time for preventing any sort of XML bomb. In [the source code](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/xlrd/xlsx.py), the xlsx data is passed to python's built-in `xml.etree` for parsing without any validation:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def process_stream(self, stream, heading=None):
        if self.verbosity >= 2 and heading is not None:
            fprintf(self.logfile, "\n=== %s ===\n", heading)
        self.tree = ET.parse(stream)
```

### However, it may be possible to patch `ElementTree` using defusedxml

As noted in the comments, [defusedxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/defusedxml/) is a package targeted directly at the problem of security against different types of XML bombs. From the docs:

> Instead of:
>
> ```
> from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
> et = parse(xmlfile)
> ```
>
> alter code to:
>
> ```
> from defusedxml.ElementTree import parse
> et = parse(xmlfile)
> ```

It also provides the functionality of patching the standard library. Since that is what xlrd is using, you are able to use the combination of xlrd and defusedxml to read Excel files while protecting yourself from XML bombs.

> Additionally the package has an **untested** function to monkey patch all stdlib modules with defusedxml.defuse_stdlib().

Comment: I tried to use defusedxml and it does not handle xml bomb at all.
maybe I am not using it well, but I tested its basic functionality and it only blocked xml containing entities, DTD etc.
there is another python package called defusedexpat which tend to handle xml bomb, but unfortunately also didn't work well.